How to refresh a token when token expires in a go backend application
In my go backend application I generated a token when my app is initialised.And I want to use this token as a global variable for further authentications.
type Token struct {
    Name         string
    Value        string
    RefreshValue string
    Expires      time.Time
}

func main() {
   AppToken := GetToken()
   router := mux.NewRouter()
   router.HandleFunc("/employees", GetEmployeesHandler).Methods("GET")
}
func GetEmployeesHandler (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    //here i want to pass token, here i validate token and check token is expired
    //check token function checks token is valid and if token 
    //expired,  check token updates AppToken.
    err := CheckToken(AppToken)
    if err != nil {
       return err
    }
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "API is up and running")
}

My requirement is that whenever the token expires I want to refresh the token I also want to ensure the refresh token should be blocked when there is already a refresh token process that is taking place. Please help me.

Take a look to sync package (https://pkg.go.dev/sync)

@xflr6 I know what you are thinking about, but this problem has nothing to do with synchronization (mutex) as the OP is trying to return back the token to the user (Stateless). So I don't think you need a Mutex, instead you need a helper function!

Is this related to oauth2?
